# Sort int-arraylist like other int-arraylist (not same indexOf values)

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist

I am new here please be patient with me. I found many answers to my question but not exactly what i am looking for.

My first `Array<Integer>` is: `["0","1","53","14","3"]`

My second `Array<Integer>` is: `["53","1","3"]`

How can I sort the second array like the first?
It should be: second-array sorted: `["1","53","3"]`?

Thank you very much! Have a nice day

Comment: By using `Arrays.sort` with a custom `Comparator` that uses the second array to determine order.

Comment: did you try **`Collections.sort(ArrayList)`**

Comment: Is it correct that second array has only one item?

Comment: Is it about sorting OR splitting & sorting one item to three items, please be more specific what you want.

Comment: It looks like intersection first array by second. But what if first array doesn't contains some value from second? On which position it should be placed?

Comment: The second Array<Integer> always contains values of the first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List1:(0,1,53,14,3)

List2:(53,1,3)

[image]

sort index:

[image]

you can get the sorted List2:(1,53,3);